# Connection For simulation touch using 1ch relay

Tags: arduino, relay, raspberry-pi, touchscreen

http://gameautomators.com/book/Electronics/4-simulation.html

Hi 
here is a reference to make a touch simulation with rpi and 1ch relay
I can't understand how to connect gpios with relay.

There are DC+ / DC- / Ch1 / NC / NO connectors in my relay.(OMRON G3MB-202P)

PLZ SEE attached image.

Green GPIO(pin4) : DC+

Blue GND : NC

Red GND : DC-

Green Output : Ch1

is that right?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The relay you are using is in fact [a phototriac](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/307/g3mb_0609-298620.pdf). This will not work for a DC application like yours.

What you need is an electromechanical relay, or, better, a transistor or phototransistor (as suggested in the link you provided).

EDIT

Please give this a try:

[image]

Comment: Can you draw a connection diagram of transistor?